# How to parse optional arguments without keyval?

Tags: pstricks, best-practices, programming, fp

The current implementation only supports rounding with the specified digits in the optional arguments.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

% \pstVerb concatenator
\def\LoadConstants{}

% Constant declarator invoked in the preamble
\newcommand\const[3][]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \edef\temporary{#3}%
    \else
        \edef\temporary{round(#3:#1)}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\expandafter{\temporary}}%
    \toks0=\expandafter{\LoadConstants\pstVerb}
    \edef\LoadConstants{\the\toks0 {/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}}

\makeatletter
\def\pst@@picture@i[#1]#2(#3,#4){%
% BEGIN - redefine \const for invocation inside pspicture
    \renewcommand\const[3][]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{##1}\relax
        \edef\temporary{##3}%
    \else
        \edef\temporary{round(##3:##1)}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname##2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\expandafter{\temporary}}%
        \pstVerb{/##2 \csname##2\endcsname\space def}\ignorespaces}%
% END - redefine \const for invocation inside pspicture
    \@ifnextchar(% ignore anything between [] and ()
% BEGIN - inject \LoadConstants into pspicture
    {\pst@@@picture[#1](#3,#4)\LoadConstants}%
    {\pst@@@picture[#1](0,0)(#3,#4)\LoadConstants}%
% END - inject \LoadConstants into pspicture    
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=25pt\relax


\SpecialCoor
\const{Side}{root(2,17)}% the square root of 17

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}   
\begin{pspicture}(\Side,\Side)
    \psframe(!Side dup)\pause
    \multido{\i=0+30}{12}{%
        \const[5]{temp}{cos(\i*pi/180)}
        \rput{\i}(!Side 2 div dup dup \i\space PtoC 3 1 roll add 3 1 roll add){$\temp$}\pause
    }
\end{pspicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Objective:

I want to make `\const` behave as follows. If we invoke

- `\const[4,r]{...}{...}`, it will use `round` with 4 digits after .
- `\const[4,t]{...}{...}`, it will use `trunc` with 4 digits after .
- `\const[c]{...}{...}`, it will use `clip` to trim all trailing zeros

Any idea to improve the code is welcome!

Comment: What will happen if the input is `\const[3]{...}{...}`

Comment: @MarcoDaniel: It is not allowed.

Comment: Then you want two optional arguments. If you use `pstricks` you already have available a key-value syntax; why not exploiting it?

Comment: @egreg: I have not learnt it yet. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\def\zzA#1,#2#3\relax#4{
\if t#2 trunc(#4:#1)%
\else\if r#2 round(#4:#1)%
\else clip(#4)%
\fi\fi}

% Constant declarator invoked in the preamble
\newcommand\const[3][]{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
        \edef\temporary{#3}%
    \else
        \edef\temporary{\zzA#1,c\relax{#3}}%
\wlog{::\temporary}%
    \fi
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname
        \expandafter{\expandafter{\temporary}}%
    \toks0=\expandafter{\LoadConstants\pstVerb}
    \edef\LoadConstants{\the\toks0 {/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}}
```

produces a log of

```
::  trunc(root(2,17):4)
::  round(root(2,17):4)
:: clip(root(2,17))
```

from

```
\const{Side}{root(2,17)}% the square root of 17
\const[4,t]{Side}{root(2,17)}% the square root of 17
\const[4,r]{Side}{root(2,17)}% the square root of 17
\const[c]{Side}{root(2,17)}% the square root of 17
```

Comment: What is `#3` for in `\zzA`?

Comment: What does `\const[4]{Side}{root(2,17)}` do? It should throw an error.

Comment: @Bugbusters errors are tricky as I'm inside the edef, so currently it checks for r and t and then teh \else clause for clip picks up everything else. You could test for clip explicitly and then have an else clause that did unknwnfunction(..) so that would then generate an error later but I'm not sure taht is better, as it would error in the Postscript rather than tex.

Comment: Error should be in TeX such that it automatically stops the next compilation with GhostScript.

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\parindent=0pt    
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\def\LoadConstants{}    
\makeatletter
\def\const{\@ifnextchar[\const@i{\const@i[r]}}
\def\const@i[#1]{\expandafter\const@ii#1,,\@nil}
\def\const@ii#1,#2,#3\@nil#4#5{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax 
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax \expandafter\const@iii\expandafter{#5}{#4}%
    \else
      \pst@isnum{#1}%
        {>>> Wrong Parameter '#1' \@namedef{#4}{}}
        {\ifx#1c \expandafter\const@iii\expandafter{clip(#5)}{#4}%
         \else   \expandafter\const@iii\expandafter{#5}{#4}%
         \fi}%
    \fi%
  \else%
    \ifx#2t  \expandafter\const@iii\expandafter{trunc(#5:#1)}{#4}%
    \else
      \ifx#2c\expandafter\const@iii\expandafter{clip(#5}{#4}%
      \else  \expandafter\const@iii\expandafter{round(#5:#1)}{#4}%
      \fi%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}
\def\const@iii#1#2{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\expandafter{#1}}%
    \toks0=\expandafter{\LoadConstants\pstVerb}
    \edef\LoadConstants{\the\toks0 {/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\const{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side \\
\const[c]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side \\
\const[4]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side \\
\const[r]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side\\
\const[6,r]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side\\
\const[6,t]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side
\end{document}
```

[image]

An empty argument like `\const[]{...` is also possible.

And here the same with the key/value syntax:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\parindent=0pt
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage[nomessages]{fp}

\def\LoadConstants{}
\makeatletter
\define@key[psset]{}{Roundtype}[round]{\expandafter\pst@@Roundtype#1\@nil}%
\def\pst@@Roundtype#1#2\@nil{%
  \ifx#1t \def\psk@Roundtype{trunc}%
    \else\ifx#1c \def\psk@Roundtype{clip}\else\def\psk@Roundtype{round}%
  \fi\fi}
\define@key[psset]{}{Decimals}[-1]{\pst@getint{#1}\psk@Decimals}%
\psset{Roundtype,Decimals}
\def\pst@RT@c{clip}

\def\const{\def\pst@par{}\pst@object{const}}
\def\const@i#1#2{%
  \use@par%
  \ifx\psk@Roundtype\pst@RT@c
    \expandafter\const@ii\expandafter{clip(#2)}{#1}
  \else
    \ifnum\psk@Decimals<1\relax
      \expandafter\const@ii\expandafter{#2}{#1}%
    \else
      \expandafter\const@ii\expandafter{\psk@Roundtype(#2:\psk@Decimals)}{#1}%
    \fi%
  \fi%
}

\def\const@ii#1#2{%
    \expandafter\FPeval\csname#2\expandafter\endcsname\expandafter{\expandafter{#1}}%
    \toks0=\expandafter{\LoadConstants\pstVerb}
    \edef\LoadConstants{\the\toks0 {/#2 \csname#2\endcsname\space def}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\const{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side \\
\const[Roundtype=c]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side \\
\const[Decimals=4]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side \\
\const[Roundtype=r]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side\\
\const[Decimals=6,Roundtype=r]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side\\
\const[Decimals=6,Roundtype=t]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side\\
\const[]{Side}{root(2,17)} \Side
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you make the compilation in TeX phase terminated with an error message when invoking `\const[4]{Side}{root(2,17)}`?

Comment: `\@pstrickserr{Invalid argument!}\@ehpb`

Comment: The key/value version behaves strange, for example: (1) `\const{}{}` should produce 18 digits after period. (2) `\const[Roundtype=c,Decimals=4]` does not make sense.

Comment: then set the default to 18 digits. Where is the ptoblem?? I have no idea what makes sense or not. I do not use the fp package for that!

Comment: How to set the default to 18? I don't think it is possible because it will throw an error. Only 17 is the max when using `trunc` and `round`.

Comment: When `Roundtype=c`, `\const` must ignore `Decimals` because `clip` is invented to clip trailing zeros (if any).

Comment: I modified it. You can do it yourself, the code is really simple.